# How can i create a new card by clicking on a button (js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript. The button i wanna make should add every single time clicking it a new card to my web page. Unfortunatly my code does not work. Can you guys help me?

My Code:
html:

```
    <div class="plus">+</div>
 <button onclick="newPerson()" class="plus">
     <div class="item">
     <p>title</p>
 </div>
 </button>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
<div class="item">
     <p>Title</p>
 </div>
```

javaScript Code :

```
function newPerson() {
document.getElementByClassName("item")
};
```

Comment: use the document.createElement methid

Comment: function newPerson() {
    document.createElement("item")
};well it dident work what should i do?

Comment: @Reto.K after creating element you have to insert it into document with appendChild(): https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/appendChild

Comment: @Reto.K I have added the answer. It works on my pc.

Comment: Thanks it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button.plus").on("click",function(){

$("div:last").after("<div class=item><p>Title</p></div>");

    })

})
```

This is Demo : [UpdatedDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/taghdisi/8nxpwrk0/4/)

Comment: As i said it works now. there is just one problem with this code the css to this cards witch i can add now are not working anymore. the class styled it also with the class item ...Do you also have a solution to this?

Comment: @Reto.K , explain problem with example please

Comment: so this is the porblem since i changed the js code and the html a bit it does not recognise this code. css code: .item {
    width:300px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:10px;}

Comment: @Reto.K , See UpdatedDemo.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
 <div id = "main">
 //your same html code

 </div>

 <script>
function newPerson() {
var newdiv  = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.className+='item';

var newp = document.createElement('p');
newp.innerHTML = "TItle";

newdiv.appendChild(newp);
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(newdiv);
}
 </script>
```

You need to create the element through JS and append it to the document

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to solve it:

```js
function newPerson() {
  $('#wrapper').append('<div class="item"><p>Title</p></div>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="plus">+</div>
  <button onclick="newPerson()" class="plus">
    <div class="item">
      <p>title</p>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```